# What's the fastest way to check which values I've used so far in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

A snippet

```
if (a<=lim){
    if(std::find(prims.begin(), prims.end(), a)==prims.end()){
        prims.push_back(a);
        count+=lim/a;
    }         
}
```

So basically I have this part in my code where I add the variable `a` into this `vector` if it isn't already present, and then I update a counter on the fly.

But I am wondering if this is suboptimal in terms of runtime. Anything faster I can do?

Comment: Does the end result have to be a vector? Or could you just replace it with a data structure that is better at searching for elements, such as `set` or `unordered_set`?

Comment: You can hash the ints, or, if you know that your array is sorted, you can binary search. The first is constant time under the uniform hashing assumption. The second is log N.

Comment: @jogojapan Doesn't have to be anything -- I just want some way to be able to say "Have I encountered $a$ before? If so, remember this new $a$, do count+=lim/a, and go on about the day" in the fastest way possible that doesn't require a massive array where I just lookup an index or something (since the values of $a$ may range from 0 to trillions so there's insufficient memory for such a table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) Is a container that is used commonly if you want to only keep unique values.
Values are internally stored as red-black trees so most operations are of logarithmic complexity.

This would be faster than your implementation, and about as fast as the suggested binary search implementation.

You can improve it further by using the new (c++11) [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), which stores it as a hash table, which would make it even faster at average constant time operations.

Use `set` as follows

```
std::set<TYPE> prims;
....
if (a<=lim){
    if(prims.insert(a).second){
        count+=lim/a;
    }         
}
```

where TYPE is the type of the values stored in your vector

Comment: Is this faster than what I am doing now? What about unordered sets?

Comment: I dont think I have new C++11

Comment: In that case you can go with `std::set` or try to get a unordered_set like container from boost, depending on how important the speed is.

Comment: replace `push_back` with [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) and `std::find` with [member function version- std::set::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find)

Comment: You can probably use the return value of insert itself, instead of explicitly doing find.

Comment: I don't really understand this link. I just wrote #include <set> up top. Do I just change the word "vector" to set and then change push_back to insert?

Comment: This is much faster! Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! If speed is so important to you, and portability is NOT, you can see if you can use [`stdext::hash_set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t4xas78(v=vs.80).aspx) provided by microsoft, more info [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/28387/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `std::unordered_set` to check for duplicates, which gives you `O(1)` *amortized* lookup.

If you kind of know the maximum size of `a` and it's fairly small, you can use a `bool` array to store whether element `x` and you'll have true `O(n)` lookup.

Comment: The bool array was my first idea, but $a$ has a very large range that can't be kept in memory. How does unordered_set work and how is it different from set in terms of speed?

Comment: @KaliMa then go with `unordered_set`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use other STL containers with uniqueness builtin, like the *set*, or *map*; http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/.
For example, a hashtable modeled by a map, fits your use case.

```
<map>
using namespace std;

int insert_and_update(int key_val,map<int,int> hash_map) {
map<int,int>::iterator it;
it = hash_map.find(key_val);
  if( it != hash_map::end() ) {
     it->second += 1; //contains the associated value.
     return 1;
  }
 hash_map(key_val) = 1; //else insert new key into map
 return 0;      
}
```

Comment: Is it really applicable, though? Since I'd have no reason to insert a value multiple times. I want to only insert something if it doesn't exist because then I am able to update my count variable.